# SQLite in Gradle project

Tags: sqlite, gradle

My project cannot build after adding sqlite.
I added string

```
compile group:'org.xerial', name:'sqlite-jdbc', version:'3.33.0'
```

to dependencies section of build.gradle, downloaded SQLite and added it to System Path.
Error text is "Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.33.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.33.0/sqlite-jdbc-3.33.0.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration."
> Should I add something to repositories section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There error is quite clear:

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'. **Could not find org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.33.0**. Searched in the following locations: (...)

If you look at the latest release: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/tags

3.33.0 does not exist. Nor does it exist in Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc

Switch to version that is available such as 3.32.3.2